# GCP, only list buckets where user has permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to figure out a way to allow a GCP user to list buckets but only those where the user has permissions (through ACL). The reason is because it can be overwhelming the number of buckets and the user experience would not be the best. Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) You cannot restrict listing buckets. 2) Do not create so many buckets in the same project eg use more than one project.

Comment: @JohnHanley completely disagree, there's a reason why we're allow to created multiple buckets. Many of us who offer services don't want to create a whole new project for each clients private data.

Comment: @OliverDixon - What are you disagreeing with? Item 1 is a fact. Item 2, I made a suggestion, you can design your projects as you wish.

Comment: @JohnHanley isn't that obvious?

Comment: @OliverDixon - No it is not obvious. There are many factors that you should consider when designing a storage system. Using multiple buckets is usually a good idea. However, having a large number of buckets will slow down access. The metadata for Cloud Storage is stored in Spanner and queries that return large amounts of information take time. Read some of the whitepapers on Colossus and Spanner for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to figure out a way to allow a GCP user to list buckets
>   but only those where the user has permissions (through ACL).

You cannot accomplish your goal using either Bucket ACLs or IAM permissions.

To list Google Cloud Storage buckets, you need the IAM permission `storage.buckets.list`.

This permission grants the IAM member account permission to list all buckets in the project. You cannot restrict this permission further to list only specific bucket names. This permission does not allow listing the objects in a bucket.

For a future design decision, you can use different projects and organize your buckets under projects. This will limit access to only IAM members of that project.

When you create a bucket you permanently define its name, location and the project it is part of. These characteristics cannot be changed later.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, the problem that we could see so far is that we need to isolate around 2000k+ buckets and growing, so it comes with another complexity regarding to manage the gcp projects itself

Comment: What - 2 million buckets? I am surprised that GCP is allowing that. I would love to know the use case for that design.

Comment: wanted to mean 2k, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the CLI, you can write a script that gets the permissions for each listed bucket, and only displays it if the user account is in the permission list:

```
for bucket in $(gsutil ls); do 
    if  gsutil acl get $bucket|grep -q $(gcloud config get-value account) ; then
        echo $bucket; 
    fi; 
done
```

Note that inherited permissions (e.g. at the project level) will not appear with this script.

This can't be accomplished with the console, but if you need a web interface listing only certain buckets, then you can build it yourself by calling the API and doing the same thing that the CLI script does.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but we would like to leverage the  console for this